# How to charge different amount on an order after processing via WooCommerce API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Take this example:

A user places an order for 2 items on a WooCommerce shop. The order is picked up (using REST) by a POS (Point-of-Sale) system. The owner discovers that only one of the items is available (for whatever reason) and decides to amend the order by removing the non-existing item.

How does the POS system tell WooCommerce (via REST API) that the order is "completed" (so that WooCommerce plug-in can do the capture (charge) of the payment at the payment provider), but at the same time tells WooCommerce that it should only charge the price for the one item, and not the price registered on the order?

In another shop we manage, we can tell the shop the amount to charge when we change the order status to "completed" - how do we do this properly in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

Some payment methods e.g. PayPal allows you to authorize (reserve the amount) without capturing it right away, so this could be used to address your issue in the following flow:

1. Payment method payment action is set to **Authorize** to reserve the funds on customers account.
2. Customer places an online order.
3. POS system calls `GET /wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>` to retrieve order details.
4. Optional. Changes are made to order items and `PUT /wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>` Rest API endpoint called to update the order details.
5. Another `PUT /wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>` request is made to change order status from processing to completed. This will trigger payment method to **capture** the funds based on current order total.

Note: It might be possible to combine steps 4 and 5.

Option 2:

If payment method you are using does not support authorizations, your other option is refunds.

1. Payment method configured to **capture** the funds.
2. Customer places an online order.
3. POS system calls `GET /wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>` to retrieve order details.
4. `PUT /wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>` request is made to change order status from processing to completed.
5. A refund in desired amount can be created by calling `POST /wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>/refunds` end point.

Note: Some payment methods do not support partial refunds. A REST API call will be needed to update order and remove products that could not be shipped. You may need to test when it is the best time to make such call so it does not affect refund/order totals.

Comment: Thank you - I was hoping that I could do it without having to re-issue the order (it can be difficult to synchronize back from our POS system to WooCommerce), but if that's the only way to do it in WooCommerce, then that's what we have to do... Like I said, in another web shop, we can specify the amount to charge when we set the order status to "completed". Perhaps the Refunds option is easier to implement into our current system...